# Calling Oracle Procedure from VB.NET only works the first 2 times

Tags: vb.net, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm working on a project that reads in a file, calls a Oracle stored procedure for each line of the file, renames a file based on the returned value from the procedure, and moves the file to a server.  I've got all of that working, but for some reason, the procedure is only returning a value first two times it is called.  After that, I'm getting nothing back.  I've tried closing the connection in the loop and reopening it, but that does not help.  I'd also really rather not have to do that.

Names have been changed to protect the innocent servers.

```
Do While Not endOfData
    Dim dataRecord As String = dataReader1.GetRecord
    If dataRecord = "End of Data" Then
        endOfData = True
    Else
        ' Read in record '
        indexRec = indexLoader.LoadPointerIndex(dataRecord, PointerIndexRecordType.Original)

        'Format date values '
        effdate = indexRec.EffDate.ToString("M/dd/yyyy")
        dir = "/" & easyFile & "/" & indexRec.EffDate.Year & "/" & indexRec.EffDate.Month & "/"


        'Connect to Oracle '
        Dim conn As New OracleConnection(connString)
        conn.Open()
        'Call proc with indexRec values '
        Dim myCMD As New OracleCommand()
        myCMD.Connection = conn
        myCMD.CommandText = "SCHEMA.PROC"
        myCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        'Setup Parameters '
        myCMD.Parameters.Add("P_CONTRACT_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10, Nothing, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = indexRec.Contract
        myCMD.Parameters.Add("P_EFFT_DATE", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = indexRec.EffDate
        myCMD.Parameters.Add("P_DIRECTORY", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 18, Nothing, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = dir
        myCMD.Parameters.Add("P_FILENAME_OUT", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 13, Nothing, ParameterDirection.Output)

        myCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Result = CType(myCMD.Parameters("P_FILENAME_OUT").Value.ToString, String)
        myCMD.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()

        'Rename PDF based on returned result '
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(rootDirectory & "\" & configSettings.appFolder & "\" & indexRec.Contract & ".pdf", Result)

        'Verify that folder exists on server '
        sFolder = sDir & indexRec.EffDate.Year & "\" & indexRec.EffDate.Month
        If (Not Directory.Exists(sFolder)) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(sDir & indexRec.EffDate.Year & "\" & indexRec.EffDate.Month)
        End If

        'Move PDF to proper folder '
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(rootDirectory & "\" & configSettings.appFolder & "\" & Result, sFolder & "\" & Result)
    End If
Loop
```

Here is the Proc that another team manages.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE PROC(P_CONTRACT_ID  IN VARCHAR2,
               P_EFFT_DATE    IN DATE,
               P_DIRECTORY    IN VARCHAR2,
               P_FILENAME_OUT OUT VARCHAR2)
--*****************************************************
    -- Name: PROC
    -- Purpose: Insert a contract statement                                       
    -- Authored by: 
    -- Created on: 
    -- Modifications:
    -- Seq Who Date Description
    -- ----------------------------------------------------
    -- 001 DAT 08/27/2012 Initial Release
    --*****************************************************
 AS

    V_CONTRACT_UID       NUMBER;
    V_CORRESPONDENCE_UID NUMBER;
    V_DEL_COUNT          NUMBER;
    V_NEW_FILE_URL       VARCHAR2(254);

BEGIN

    --Get the contract_uid
    SELECT CONTRACT_UID
       INTO V_CONTRACT_UID
       FROM ODS.CONTRACTS
       WHERE CONTRACT_ID = P_CONTRACT_ID;

    --If existing, delete the entry and add (dont do a merge).
    SELECT COUNT(CORRESPONDENCE_UID)
      INTO   V_DEL_COUNT
      FROM   CORRESPONDENCES
      WHERE  CONTRACT_UID = V_CONTRACT_UID
             AND TRUNC(CORRESPONDENCE_CREATION_DATE) = TRUNC(P_EFFT_DATE);

    IF V_DEL_COUNT > 0 THEN
      DELETE FROM CORRESPONDENCES
        WHERE  CORRESPONDENCE_UID IN
                  (SELECT CORRESPONDENCE_UID
                     FROM   CORRESPONDENCES
               WHERE  CONTRACT_UID = V_CONTRACT_UID
                 AND TRUNC(CORRESPONDENCE_CREATION_DATE) = TRUNC(P_EFFT_DATE));
    END IF;

    -- *** Create Correspondence Row and New File Name ***
    -- *** Create new file name ***
    V_CORRESPONDENCE_UID := CORRESPONDENCES_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
    P_FILENAME_OUT       := RTRIM(LTRIM(TO_CHAR(V_CORRESPONDENCE_UID) || '.pdf'));
    V_NEW_FILE_URL       := 'http://armstorage.integritycompanies.com' || P_DIRECTORY || P_FILENAME_OUT;

    INSERT INTO CORRESPONDENCES
        (CORRESPONDENCE_UID,
         CORRESPONDENCE_TYPE,
         CORRESPONDENCE_CREATION_DATE,
         CORRESPONDENCE_CONTENT_TYPE,
         CORRESPONDENCE_IMAGE_FILE_NAME,
         CORRESPONDENCE_IMAGE_FILE_EXT,
         CORRESPONDENCE_UPDATED,
         CORRESPONDENCE_URL,
         CORRESPONDENCE_DESC,
         CONTRACT_UID)
    VALUES
        (V_CORRESPONDENCE_UID,
         'ST',
         P_EFFT_DATE,
         'application/pdf',
         P_FILENAME_OUT,
         '.pdf',
         SYSDATE,
         V_NEW_FILE_URL,
         'Contract Statement',
         V_CONTRACT_UID);

    COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
        ROLLBACK;

END;
```

Any suggestions or requests?

Comment: Honestly that is a debug job. What have you tried? It is hard to say by just looking at the code. Can you put logs into the plsql code?

Comment: My first question is why you're opening/closing/re-opening a connection inside of the loop.  If it's the same connection, open it outside of the loop (and close it outside of the loop).  Also for performance, you can setup the OracleCommand outside of the loop and then re-use it inside of the loop if it's calling the same proc everytime (you just change the values at that point).

Comment: Having nothing returned in the output parameter suggests that an exception is being raised.  I suggest changing your exception handler to stuff the exception text into the output parameter - and allocate enough space in the output parameter to allow for such an occurence - looks like it's only 13 characters long at present.  Good luck.

Comment: Could you create a log table and have the proc insert into it between each command. You are not catching exceptions in your VB.NET so possibly missing issues - for instance Null variables, when you get the contract_uid, variables in the insert are too large (V_NEW_FILE_URL).

Comment: One alternative you could try is to use Oracle Array Binding for the parameters.  Instead of looping, and opening the connection each loop (which could realistically be the issue in this case) you would create an array for each value in your loop and pass them in as parameters.  Our testing found them to be significantly faster than other methods of saving to the database.

Comment: A couple notes.

I originally opened and closed the connection outside of the loop, and I was trying to see if closing inside the loop fixed the issue.  I know that is bad coding, but I was trying to see what would work.

There's more code outside of this loop including initializing variables and it is contained in a try catch block.  

No exception is being returned when I get null, so I'll check with the db programmer to see if they can add that in.  I can't modify the proc, just request changes.

I'll check out the Array Binding and see if that helps out.

Comment: Figured it out.  More debugging was required.  The proc was changed to include checking one of the values I send it against another table.  If no result is returned, I get null back from the call.  Added criteria to check for that, and I'm good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Proc was looking for one of the parameters I passed, and checking for its' value on another table I didn't have access to.  If the value isn't found, a "null" value is returned.  Some criteria to check for that issue corrected the problem.